# How to create a dropdown without position relative/ absolute (alternatives for dropdowns)?

Tags: css

Following is the code for a dropdown menu.

I'm searching for alternatives for creating dropdown menu without using relative/absolute.

Since relative/absolute is commonly used I want a different solution.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm searching for an alternative just because of this::

[How to prevent a child component with position relative do not appear above the table head (or on top - z-depth) with sticky header in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272309/how-to-prevent-a-child-component-with-position-relative-do-not-appear-above-the)

Wherever I use relative it is appearing above the sticky headers of tables. That's why.

Comment: *Since relative/absolute is commonly used I want a different solution.* --> this doesn't really make sense. Why would you want a solution *not* commonly used?

Comment: It's because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272309/how-to-prevent-a-child-component-with-position-relative-do-not-appear-above-the

Comment: Although you obviously need some solution, please don't spread your request for help over two different questions and have us jump all over the place. Furthermore, add some CSS you are using ([reprex]), don't expect people to guess whats happening and refer to the manual for background on the app you're creating.

Comment: css is simple man. it's the same css rules name converted in to classes. It's simply tailwind. Straightforward.

Comment: I made myself clear that relative is causing table header sticky to break. I just wanted to isolate the problem. Otherwise people would get confused. That's why!! Please suggest something if you can. I've been trying out my own solutioins for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply enough, you just need to use the sibling selector '+' and hide/show the sibling of `.dropdown>span` which is `.dropdown-content`:

**update** added a textline to show why `relative` and `absolute` are required. 'relative' creates a new 'stacking context' and combined with the `z-index: 1` it prevents the textline from moving up and down when hovering...

**update 2** added some CSS adn HTML to show the comparison of using without and with `position: relative` (parent container) and `position: absolute` (drowpdown content).

Do some reading on [MDN: The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;

  /* ADDED for some spacing */
  margin: 5rem; max-width: 20rem
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

/* MODDED */
.dropdown > span:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* ADDED */
.dropdown.relative         { position: relative }
.dropdown-content.absolute { position: absolute }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  <p>without new stacking context<br>z-index has no effect</p>
</div>

<div class="dropdown relative">
  <span>Mouse over me 2</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content absolute">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  <p>new stacking context<br>z-index makes dropdown overlay content</p>
</div>
```